# No on-screen keyboard when using xbox 360 controller

Tags: pc, controllers, dark-souls

I have an Xbox 360 controller for PC. I launched the game Dark Souls, and when I was asked to enter my character name, nothing would happen. The keyboard overlay didn't appear and I had to use my keyboard.

How do you enable the keyboard overlay in PC games when using an Xbox 360 controller?

Comment: pretty sure you can't...its still a computer game after all. Unless it has full controller support its not going to have the on screen keyboard. Even then...its still a computer game.

Comment: The xbox keyboard overlay is a system function that the game calls, which is why PS3 and Xbox keyboard overlays are different (duh). PC does not have a need for such a function, thus doesn't have a keyboard overlay to call.

Comment: Is it possible to create a shortcut on the controller to open the PC keyboard overlay?

Answer (score 8):

Dark Souls only comes with [Partial Controller Support](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=18) on Steam. You'll have to use your keyboard to enter text in game.

Steam has information about this support on their [Big Picture mode FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5006-ASLN-3202) page:

> **Controller Support levels:**
>
> Any Steam game can be played while in Big Picture mode, though not all Steam games support the use of a controller. Currently, Big Picture supports the Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows, the Xbox 360 Wired Controller, and the Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710. To determine whether a game is controller-enabled, please refer to the following tags:
>
> **Full Support**
>
> Titles marked with “Full Controller Support” indicate that they can be downloaded, launched and played using only a controller.  These titles do not require a mouse or keyboard on hand for any configuration or in-game setup.
>
> **Partial Support**
>
> Titles marked with “Partial Controller Support” indicate that mouse and keyboard may be required from time to time.  A controller may be used while in game, however installation,  configuration and overall user interface may only be optimized for mouse and keyboard.

---

**Non-Steam Games**

The above information is only for Steam games, non-Steam games may react differently again, and will completely depend on the developers including the feature in their game.